# How to pass field from submitted form into url in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to submit a form, save to database and then show the cleaned_data on a new url. In the form I have a field called job_number. I would like to send the cleaned_data over to 127.0.0.1:8000/quotes/job_number

quote/views.py:

```
@login_required
def quote_view(request):
    data_form = QuoteInformationForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        data_form = QuoteInformationForm(request.POST)
        if data_form.is_valid():
            data_form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('quote')
        else:
            print('Error')
    return render(request, "index.html", {'data_form': data_form})

@login_required
def submitted_quote(request):
    return render(request, "quote.html")
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', quote_view, name='home'),
    path('quote/', submitted_quote, name='quote'),
```

Currently all this does is open the form at http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/ using index.html. When I submit it will send the info to the database and redirect me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/quotes. This is fine. Now I just need to show the cleaned data on this url and change the url to include the job_number at the end. How can I do this?

Comment: It seems that you need to gain more knowledge on Django views and URLs. These might help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Yes I think so too

Answer (score 0):

you need to change url pattern like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', quote_view, name='home'),
    path('quote/<int:job_number>/', submitted_quote, name='quote'),
]
```

and submitted_quotes():

```
@login_required
def submitted_quote(request,job_number):
     job = # Get Your job
     return render(request, "quote.html", {"job":job})
```

and :

```
@login_required
def quote_view(request):
    data_form = QuoteInformationForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        data_form = QuoteInformationForm(request.POST)
        if data_form.is_valid():
            data_form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('quote{}'.format(data_form.id))
        else:
            print('Error')
    return render(request, "index.html", {'data_form': data_form})
```

Comment: i think I need to learn more about views honestly. This is a bit over my head. So I'm trying to get a working example to learn from. Currently I'm getting the error 'QuoteInformationForm' object has no attribute 'id'. In my submitted_quote I've done "job = job_number.Object.get('job_number')" - I'm guessing this is wrong. I think I should take a step back and learn now.